# Compute and edit multiple attributes in a single jQuery call

Tags: jquery, edit, attr

I need to compute new and edit both the 'x' and 'y' attributes of an SVG element (rect) using a single jQuery call.

Now I know you can do this:

```
var incBy = 20;

$('#test').attr('x', function(i, val) {
    return parseInt(val) + incBy;
});
```

which is fine for computing and editing single attributes, but how can I edit multiple attributes in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you factor it out, you can also do it in one line:

```
$('#test').attr('x', myFunction).attr('y', myFunction);

function myFunction(i, val) {
  return parseInt(val) + incBy; 
}
```

Or abstract it more and pass into a separate function the attributes you want to apply this to

```
process('x', 'y');

function process() {
  for (var i = 0; i < process.arguments.length; i++)
    $('test').attr(process.arguments[i]), myfunction);

  function myFunction(i, val) {
    return parseInt(val) + incBy; 
  }
}
```

It depends on how far you want to go. You could include the function to be called in the parameters, and the selection criteria too.

Comment: Thank you for making it look good @Tomalak! I need to practice more.

Comment: Never mind. :) It's one of the nicer features of the site that you can (with enough reputation) edit every post.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using a map with jQuery's attr method.

```
$('#test').attr(
        {'x': editValue,
         'y': editValue
        });
function editValue(i, val) {
   return parseInt(val) + incBy;
};
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know that. It's still *two* function calls nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

```
var incBy = 20;

$('#test').each(function () {
    this.x += incBy;
    this.y += incBy;
});
```

or, more elegantly, this (also has higher performance if you want to modify *thousands* of objects)

```
$.fn.extend({
  modCoordsBy: function(amount) {
    for (var i=0, j=this.length; i<j; i++) {
      this[i].x += amount;
      this[i].y += amount;
    }
    return this;
  }
});

$('#test').modCoordsBy(20);
```

Apply range checks or type tests to `x` and `y` as you see fit.

Comment: So simple...how did I overlook it! If that works I'll kick myself in the mouth ;)

Comment: Prepare for your mouth to be kicked LOL :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of a way to do it on multiple attributes, but if you are looking for a way to prevent duplicate code, you can refactor out the anonymous function.

```
$('#test').attr('x', myFunction);
$('#test').attr('y', myFunction);

function myFunction(i, val) {
    return parseInt(val) + incBy;
}
```